# C++ Win32 Multiline static label

Tags: c++, winapi, label

I'm having a problem with multiple lines on a label.

I've tried using ES_MULTILINE, but whenever I use that I get a grey/black rectangle on the location of the label, without the text of the label.

```
CreateWindowW(L"STATIC", selectedPatternProblem, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC,500, 190, 380, 90,*hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);
```

And when I add WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, the rectangle is gone, but so is my text.
The 'selectedPatternProblem' is too big to display on just one line, so my question is:

How can I display my label on multiple lines?

**Edit:** After deleting ES_MULTILINE and WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, I found out my word was too long. But now I wonder how can I display one long word on multiple lines?

Comment: Re: your edit, to my knowledge the static control does not support breaking words when wrapping. You would either have to implement your own custom control, or use an owner-drawn static control (and provide your own drawing routine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using an edit control style (`ES_MULTILINE`) with a static control, which is not designed to support it. That style probably maps to `SS_BLACKRECT` or `SS_GRAYRECT`, which would explain the behavior you're observing.

You should not have to add any style to your current control to achieve what you want, because you're already specifying `SS_LEFT`, and the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773.aspx) says:

> **SS_LEFT**
>
> A simple rectangle and left-aligns the text in the rectangle. The text
>   is formatted before it is displayed. Words that extend past the end of
>   a line are automatically wrapped to the beginning of the next
>   left-aligned line. Words that are longer than the width of the control
>   are truncated.

Since you're specifying neither `SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP` nor one of the `SS_*ELLIPSIS` styles, the text should wrap between word boundaries.

Note you're also using the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` *message* as a style, which will definitely not work as you expect. You should remove that value from your control's styles.

Answer (score 2):

ES_MULTILINE is suitable for Edit controls not labels

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Designates a multiline edit control. The default is single-line edit
>   control.
>
> When the multiline edit control is in a dialog box, the default
>   response to pressing the ENTER key is to activate the default button.

Answer (score 1):

I used an edit control  as an alternative to multi line edit control. I had set the following properties in resource file

`EDITTEXT IDC_COMMENT,58,53,75,41,ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | NOT WS_BORDER`