# Win API, How to write text inside a dialog box?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dialog

I'm creating a small program of my own on WinAPI, (to practice the WIN API programing)
and I wanted to create an "about us" box, like where it is told who built the program, which version is it and such...

I was able to create the window sucsessfully, though I could only created an empty window..
I was wondering how can I write text in the box?

This is my function that creates the dialog box, where ghInstance is the instance of the window :

```
void CreateDialogBox(HWND hwnd)
{
CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_TOPMOST,  TEXT("DialogClass"), TEXT("About Us"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION , 100, 100, 200, 150, NULL, NULL, ghInstance,  NULL);
}
```

So how can I write inside that empty window some stuff?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial, provided by Microsoft (MSDN) themselves should come in handy:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384843.aspx

Take note of the `WM_PAINT` section.  That's for drawing simple text.

You can also create controls on the window, for example:
[C++ Win32 Multiline static label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198099/c-win32-multiline-static-label)

Comment: You should use a text control so that the program is accessible. Actually, you should just use a system dialog box, which will do pretty much everything for you.

Comment: Thank you, I've used controls instead :)
and I did not want to use MessageBox, but to write one of my own :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS VC++, you can try editing the pre-made About us in the resource script. Or you hand craft it in a resource script.

```
DialogboxName DIALOGEX 0, 0, 170, 62
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About Us"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    ICON            128,IDC_STATIC,14,14,21,20
    LTEXT           "Program by you, Version 1.0",IDC_STATIC,42,14,114,8,SS_NOPREFIX
    LTEXT           "Copyright (C) 2016",IDC_STATIC,42,26,114,8
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,113,41,50,14,WS_GROUP
END
```

You can reference Charles Petzold Windows programming book, version 5 of it.

Comment: What if it is localized text, for example on different languages in my program, but in case of resource script i cannot change text dynamically because it already defined in resource script not as simple variable.